# Remove empty elements from list with character(0)

Tags: r, list

How can I remove empty elements from a list that contain zero length pairlist as
`character(0)`, `integer(0)` etc...

```
list2
# $`hsa:7476`
# [1] "1","2","3"
# 
# $`hsa:656`
# character(0)
#
# $`hsa:7475`
# character(0)
#
# $`hsa:7472`
# character(0)
```

I don't know how to deal with them. I mean if `NULL` it is much simpler. How can I remove these elements such that just `hsa:7476` remains in the list.

Answer (score 53):

Another option(I think more efficient) by keeping index where element length > 0 :

```
l[lapply(l,length)>0] ## you can use sapply,rapply

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] "foo"
```

Answer (score 40):

One possible approach is

```
Filter(length, l)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "foo"
```

where

```
l <- list(1:3, "foo", character(0), integer(0))
```

This works due to the fact that positive integers get coerced to `TRUE` by `Filter` and, hence, are kept, while zero doesn't:

```
as.logical(0:2)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: +1, I always forget about `Filter`. You can also do `Filter(function(x) !identical(character(0),x), l)` if you want to check only against `character(0)`

Comment: What's great about this is it allows the subset to be done in-line! The `lengths` approach requires having an `l` in the first place to do `l[lengths(l) > 0]`. I can apply this in the process of creating my subset.

Answer (score 24):

For the sake of completeness, the [purrr](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr) package from the popular [tidyverse](https://github.com/tidyverse) has some useful functions for working with lists - `compact` ([introduction](https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/09/29/purrr-0-1-0/)) does the trick, too, and works fine with magrittr's `%>%` pipes:

```
l <- list(1:3, "foo", character(0), integer(0))
library(purrr)
compact(l)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "foo"
```

or

```
list(1:3, "foo", character(0), integer(0)) %>% compact
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `lengths()` to define lengths of the list elements:

```
l <- list(1:3, "foo", character(0), integer(0))
l[lengths(l) > 0L]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "foo"
#>
```

Comment: I'm wondering what does `L` mean in `l[lengths(l) > 0L]` sentence ?

Comment: Force integer type.

Comment: From `?lengths`: One raison d'être of `lengths(x)` is its use as a more efficient version of `sapply(x, length)` and similar `*apply` calls to `length`.

Answer (score 15):

Funny enough, none of the many solutions above remove the empty/blank character string: `""`. But the trivial solution is not easily found: `L[L != ""]`.

To summarize, here are some various ways to remove unwanted items from an array list.

```r
# Our Example List:
L <- list(1:3, "foo", "", character(0), integer(0))

# 1. Using the *purrr* package:
library(purrr)
compact(L)

# 2. Using the *Filter* function:
Filter(length, L)

# 3. Using *lengths* in a sub-array specification:
L[lengths(L) > 0]

# 4. Using *lapply* (with *length*) in a sub-array specification:
L[lapply(L,length)>0]

# 5. Using a sub-array specification:
L[L != ""]

# 6. Combine (3) & (5)
L[lengths(L) > 0 & L != ""]
```