# Return all matches of multiple strings to column with R

Tags: r, string-matching

I have a data frame with one column, containing one or two names. I want to create a second column that returns matched names from a list, separated by a semicolon. I've tried using stringr and grepl, but can't quite get there.

Here's an example of my table and list of names I want to extract.

```
beatles.list <- c("JOHN LENNON", "PAUL MCCARTNEY", "RINGO STARR", "GEORGE HARRISON")
people = c("JOHN W. LENNON|PAUL MCCARTNEY SIR", "RINGO STARR", "CHARLES HARRISON", "GEORGE HARRISON")
beatles.data <- data.frame(people)
```

And here's what I want the resulting table to look like.

```
people = c("JOHN W. LENNON|PAUL MCCARTNEY SIR", "RINGO STARR", "CHARLES HARRISON", "GEORGE HARRISON")
beatles = c("LENNON; MCCARTNEY", "STARR", "", "HARRISON")
beatles.data <- data.frame(people, beatles)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the tidyverse. Please note that your `beatles.list` won't be helpful for matching with `people` to provide the desired output. In my example, I modified it with a lookbehind, I also added a space after the semicolon in the `paste` function, as this is what you put in your example.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43146829/6086135, for why `compact` is needed.

```
library(tidyverse)
beatles.list <- c("(?<=JOHN (W. ){0,1})LENNON", "(?<=PAUL )MCCARTNEY", "(?<=RINGO )STARR", "(?<=GEORGE )HARRISON")
  people = c("JOHN W. LENNON|PAUL MCCARTNEY SIR", "RINGO STARR", "CHARLES HARRISON", "GEORGE HARRISON")
  beatles.data <- data.frame(people)  

  beatles.data %>% 
    rowwise() %>% #needed here when supplying a vector to str_extract
    mutate(
      beatles = people %>% 
        str_extract_all(beatles.list) %>% 
        compact() %>% #removes the empty elements from the list
        paste(collapse = "; ") # to provide the desired output
    )
```

Comment: Except by removing first names you now match with an unwanted row, `Charles Harrison`.

Comment: yes i was a little to fast. fixed the answer now :) (not a beatles fan)

Comment: `sapply(str_extract_all(beatles.data$people,paste0(sub('\\s','.*',beatles.list),collapse = '|')),function(x)paste(str_extract(x,'\\S+$'),collapse=';'))`