# R：remove the specific elements within list

Tags: r

R：how to discard the element which the characters are zero within a list.Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty elements from list with character(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023446/remove-empty-elements-from-list-with-character0)

Comment: Probably yourlist <- yourlist[lengths(yourlist) > 0]